# How to show data in JSP page after searching from database?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am simply doing a JSP/Servlet project. But I have an issue. When user enter a name in the form an action happen in `SearchController` to search data from database.But problem is, how do i display the data in a jsp page?

Below is the search form

```
<form action="SearchController">
  <input type="text" placeholder="search" name="search">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Below is the servlet

```
@WebServlet("/SearchController")
public class SearchController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SearchController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);

        String search = request.getParameter("search");

        // Connect to mysql and verify username password

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         // loads driver
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loginpublic?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=GMT", "root", "1234"); // gets a new connection

        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("select from login where search=? ");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `Ajax` is your choice

Comment: Do you have any Entity/Domain class ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide any info on the framework you use, therefore I can only advise you to google for the JSP PPR (Partial Page Refresh). Notice that there is always something behind JSP.

Something like https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/ppr.html

I.e.: if you are using ADF, you can look at 2 jsp tag attributes:

1. rendered
2. partialTrigger